# Ctrl+Shift+O keyword binding

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

The "Organized imports" keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> stopped working in the *Java* editor.

The current key bindings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in my *Eclipse* installation are shown here:
[image]

What is the correct key binding to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to "Organize imports" in the *Java* editor.

Comment: If you open a Java file what does the 'Source' menu show for the  'Organize Imports' binding?

Comment: @greg-449 The `Source` menu shows `Organize imports` but without keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I can confirm control-shift-o works with eclipse oxygen but not with sts 3.9.0 when the file editor is active ( ie click on the editor space). However it works if I click on the file on the explorer menu

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/160  has work around